# Running a Cron job daily 8 PM EST for Magento

Tags: magento, cron

Could you please help me to run my cron job daily 8 PM EST for Magento in following format

`<schedule><cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this a simple cron expression you can refer to the cron documentation directly. One thing though I think you will be restricted to the local machine time zone of the machine where this task is running.

The explanation of the five stars is here:-

```
Field          Allowed values
-----          --------------
minute         0-59
hour           0-23
day of month   1-31
month          1-12 (or names, see below)
day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
```

So daily 8 p.m. would be

```
0 20 * * *
```

Reference: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `EST` part after schedule and before cron expression to get desired result.

```
0 20 * * * TZ="America/New_York" </cron_expr></schedule>
```